# How to cancel request sent by [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:..]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I make a request with this code :

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    // Here I want to cancel Request , Request Url contains searchBar Texts
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
         NSXMLParser *p = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:reqData];
        [p setDelegate:self];
        [p parse];
    }];
}
```

Comment: if you make an instance of an NSURLConnection instead, you can call `[connection cancel]` on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue *downloadQ;
```

then,

```
    self.downloadQ = [NSOperationQueue new];
    self.downloadQ.name = @"download";

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:self.downloadQ completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        NSXMLParser *p = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:reqData];
        [p setDelegate:self];
        [p parse];
    }];
```

If you need to stop

```
NSOperation *lastOp = [self.downloadQ.operations lastObject];
    [lastOp cancel];
```

**UPDATE:**

For now, it's better to use NSURLSession, which has the proper method for this:

```
- (void)getTasksWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *dataTasks, NSArray *uploadTasks, NSArray *downloadTasks))completionHandler;
```

Then check task.originalRequest.URL for returned tasks to find the one you want to cancel.

Comment: @SanjayChangani, mark it as answer, please, if it was useful for you :)

Comment: lastOp seems to be all the time nil

Comment: Queue passed in sendAsynchronousRequest: method is for completion block execution and not for actual http request. So, this solution will never work.

Comment: @YogeshMaheshwari, you could use for this purposes sendSynchronousRequest and custom queue. it's just common idea how to implement

Comment: @Doro What are you talking about? Your solution doesn't really solve the asked problem and my comment was just pointing to that.
I know how to implement a custom queue with sendSynchronousRequest and that's what I had in my project but sendSynchronousRequest never returns 404 error it always gives request cancelled error because of which I am looking for better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Make an instance of `NSURLConnection` and call its `cancel` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use.
declare

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue *downloadQ;
```

in your code -

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
      if (self.downloadQ)
    {
        [self.downloadQ cancelAllOperations];
    }

    self.downloadQ = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    self.downloadQ.name = @"download";

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:self.downloadQ
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

           //write your code hare
     }];
}
```

Comment: [self.downloadQ cancelAllOperations]; This just sets isCancelled flag to yes. You need to manually check for isCancelled and behave accordingly.

Comment: @Skodik.o .. Sorry, Can you explain ?